# On bxslider how to set slider width 100% and next slider should be hanging on right side

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make a slide with using bxslider jquery, and this is what I want to make. click the url to see  sample image here 
[image: sample]

How to make the slide that is width 100%, and next slider should be hanging on the right side.

And This is my code

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.14/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>


    <ul class="list">
      <li>
          <div class="box">
            a
          </div>
      </li>
      <li>
          <div class="box">
           b
          </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

<style
    .box { padding:30px; text-align:center; background:gray}
    </style>

<script>

    var slider1 = $('.list').bxSlider({   
      speed: 800, 
      minSlides: 1,
      maxSlides: 1,
      moveSlides: 1 
    }); 
</script>
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/sz4eu3jq/3/

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you can play with margin and padding:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/mj4mvvd5/5/

```
.box {
    padding:30px;
    text-align:center;
    background:gray;

    margin-left: 40px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

li {
    margin-left: -40px;
}



var slider1 = $('.list').bxSlider({   
  speed: 800, 
  minSlides: 1,
  maxSlides: 1,
  moveSlides: 1,
  slideMargin: 15
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) instead.

`Here` is a codepen by Dave DeSandro showing an example

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/bNLGNZ)